# SQL Script to set DNN page permissions and add an existing module to a page

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN site with a broken login screen. All urls (incl ?ctl=login) are not displaying the account login module so I am trying to create a new login page via the SQL database only.

I am looking for a script to do 3 things (ideally as a single script):
1) create a new page
2) give this new page 'All Users' permission to 'View Tab' and 'Edit Tab'
3) add the account login module to this new page

I hope this will be a workaround to gain access to site in order to fix underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is caused by the set login (Admin Site settings > Advanced settings) page not containing a login module.
Although not a direct answer to you question, the easier way to fix this is to remove the set login page for the portal.

In DNN 5+ check out the PortalLocalization table and look for the LoginTabId, reset that to NULL  and you should be able to login again.